# display the count of the rows created in each hour in last day with 0 count when rows are not created

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below.

```
 date             |name |number

5/11/2016 17:00:50| abc |123

5/11/2016 18:00:05| def |456

5/11/2016 18:15:00 |ghi |789
```

I have to display the count of rows created in each hour in last day.
and when no rows are created in that hour, it should display the count 0.
I have a limitation of not to use a PL/SQL or multiple queries.

I have tried below query, but problem with it is that it is howing both the rows of count 0  and with the count

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE ,'HH')  - LEVEL/24 AS dates , 0 as count from dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24 union
  SELECT  TRUNC (date, 'hh') as dates, count(*) as count
  FROM table
  where  date> sysdate -1
  GROUP BY TRUNC (date, 'hh')
```

.

```
Date              |Count
04-NOV-16 08.00.00  |0
04-NOV-16 09.00.00  |0
04-NOV-16 10.00.00  |0
04-NOV-16 11.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 12.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 01.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 02.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 03.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 04.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 05.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 06.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 07.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 08.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 09.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 10.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 11.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 12.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 01.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 02.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 03.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 04.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 05.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 05.00.00  |1
05-NOV-16 06.00.00  |0
05-NOV-16 06.00.00  |2
05-NOV-16 07.00.00  |0
```

I am working on Oracle 11g and i have to display the results in single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, if you are curious below is the query which is working with correct solution

```
select t1.dates , NVL(t2.count1,0)
 from 
 (SELECT trunc(sysdate ,'HH')  - LEVEL/24 AS dates , 0 as count1 from dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24) t1 
 full outer join
( SELECT  TRUNC (Date_col, 'hh') as dates, count(*) as count1
  FROM table
  where  trunc(date_col)>sysdate -1  
  GROUP BY TRUNC (date_col, 'hh')) t2
 on t1.dates=t2.dates 
 order by t1.dates desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `union`.  You want `left join`:

```
WITH d as (
      SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'HH') - LEVEL/24 as dte
      FROM dual
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24
     )
SELECT D.dte, count(t.date) as count
FROM d LEFT JOIN
     table t
     ON d.dte = TRUNC(date, 'HH') AND date > sysdate - 1
GROUP BY d.dte
```

Comment: It is not working, it is showing the result only for the rows where row were created, and not all the hour in the day. It is working as good as, normal group by clause. :(

Comment: @AkshaySapra -  There are several problems with the logic in this query. The first problem (which causes the result the OP mentioned) is that the WHERE clause is executed after the LEFT JOIN. The "date" will be null for the hours with no transactions, so it will not pass the > test - so those hours don't make it as far as GROUP BY.

Comment: The where condition should be in the on clause.  It is now fixed.  There was also an issue with the select and group by.  I think I  posted the answer prematurely.

Comment: @GordonLinoff With Count (*) it is counting the records with 0, and displaying it as 1

Comment: SYSDAT should be SYSDATE, too. I'll fix it.

Comment: @mathguy . . . This answer seems to have curse on it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Query is  still not correct it is displaying the count as 1 when the ciunt is actually zero.

Answer (score 0):

You will notice I didn't `ORDER BY hh` which is why the output looks odd. Also, where I am it is only 11 am on 5 Nov. so I will get 0 for ALL hours looking back!

The first CTE, `inputs`, is just for testing (it is not part of the solution). In the rest of the query, replace **inputs** with your actual table name, and the same for column names (which better NOT include `date` and `number`!)

```
with
     inputs ( dt, name, nbr ) as (
     select to_date('5/11/2016 17:00:50', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'abc', 123 from dual 
       union all
     select to_date('5/11/2016 18:00:05', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'def', 456 from dual 
       union all
     select to_date('5/11/2016 18:15:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'ghi', 789 from dual
     ),
-- end test data; solution (SQL query) begins here, but add the word WITH before d (hh)
     d ( hh ) as ( 
       select trunc(sysdate, 'hh') - level/24 from dual connect by level <= 24
     )
select d.hh, coalesce(i.ct, 0) as ct
from   d left outer join (
                      select trunc(dt, 'hh') as hh, count(*) as ct
                      from   inputs
                      where  dt >= sysdate - 1
                      group by trunc(dt, 'hh')                      
                    ) i
         on d.hh = i.hh
;

HH                          CT
------------------- ----------
2016-11-04 06:00:00          0
2016-11-04 21:00:00          0
2016-11-04 19:00:00          0
2016-11-04 23:00:00          0

[............................]

2016-11-04 10:00:00          0
2016-11-04 22:00:00          0

 24 rows selected
```

Comment: What if i have million rows in that table, This query could not be used then.

Comment: @AkshaySapra - You seemed familiar with the `WITH` clause so I didn't add an explanation - the first CTE is just for testing. Delete it, keep the word `WITH` and then the definition of `d` just like in your attempt. Replace "`inputs`" with your actual table name, and same for column names.

Comment: it is not working, it is displaying dates only for 4th November,

Comment: @AkshaySapra - yes... in the definition of "d" I truncated to the beginning of the day, instead of the current HOUR. (Honestly, you could have fixed that yourself - you seem to want us to do everything.) Fixed now.